# Merge updates from master into my branch and resolve conflicts (git flow)

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

Lets say we have a situation where multiple people are working on git. Each one has different branches but files on which we are working could be same.

So I am working on myBranch (that I created from master). I make changes in it (in the meanwhile there are some updates in master -- some of the changes in files that I was working on).

So I want to continue working on my branch but also get the latest updates from master in my branch. Is the below flow right or anything missing or wrong with it.

```
    git checkout myBranch  //move to my myBranch (created from master)
    ---do some work
    git status //check if changes are shown 
    git add fileName(s)  //add changed files
    git commit -m “message” //commit changes
    git push origin myBranch //send myBranch to remote

---now assume there are some changes in master (same files that i was working on)
-- I need to get these changes from master.. so..

    git checkout master //switch to master
    git pull //gets all updates from master
    git checkout myBranch //switch to myBranch (updates from master will show up in myBranch??)
    git merge master //updates from master will be merged in my branch 
    --resolve if there are any conflicts??
    git push origin myBranch //push all changes to remote myBranch (including updates from master)
```

Ultimately after completion of my work I have to send Pull request so I want to make sure that when I send my Pull request (it has all my changes + the updates from master and all the conflicts resolved as well).

Comment: Might be better to rebase than merge to master, but this might go into opinions land easily.

Comment: so rest of it is fine if we just replace git merge master with git rebase ?

Comment: I do it exactly the same way.